# Replace Strings in R with regular expression in it dynamically

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have strings I have to replace, a ton of them exactly.

They have regular expressions in it:

```
to_replace <- c("Prop. D. Absatz Pack (w)", "Preis pro konv. Einh.", "Promopreis pro konv. Einh.")
replacing <- c("prop", "preis", "promo")

x <- c("Prop. D. Absatz Pack (w)", "test", "Promopreis pro konv. Einh.")

for (i in seq_along(to_replace)) {
    gsub(pattern = paste0("\\b", to_replace[i] , "\\b"), paste0("\\b", replacing[i], "\\b"), x)
}
```

It does not work unfortunately. Is there a way to use ALL of these `.` or `(` as normal characters, not as regular expression? Thank you!

Comment: What you ask is a regex escaping function. This is a solved  issue, but there may be another problem here with `\b` word boundaries. Use `(?<!\w)` for the left and `(?!\w)` for the right word boundary instead, and do not forget to add `perl=TRUE` to `gsub`

Comment: thank you for that link, that quotemeta function did the job :-)